# ASP.NET Core how to specify a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-core, .net-core

If i have a table as called "users" and i want give only a query for example to show user as have id > 1. 
How to do that in ASP.NET Core. 
in php you can do like that: 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='1';"; 
but how to do same with ASP.NET CORE. 
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FromSqlRaw` extension method to begin a LINQ query based on a raw SQL query. `FromSqlRaw` can only be used on query roots, that is directly on the `DbSet<>`.

**Note:`DbSet.FromSql` prior to Entity Framework Core 3.0**

For parameterized queries , you could refer to the below examples:

1)Format string

```
 var author = db.Authors.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * From Authors Where AuthorId = {0}", id).FirstOrDefault();
```

2)Create `DbParameter` objects for the provider that you are using.

```
var p1 = new SqliteParameter("@Id", id);   // parameter construction for SqLite
var author = db.Authors.FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * From Authors Where AuthorId = @Id", p1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql

Comment: I will try it and come back. Thanks